# WCF DataContract DataMember order?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Is the xml that is created from your DataContract created in alphabetical order.  I have a DataContract class defined as:

```
[DataContract(Name = "User", Namespace = "")]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

When I did the following POST:

```
<User>
   <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
   <LastName>123</LastName>
   <Email>email@email.com</Email>
   <Password>pass</Password>
</User>
```

When I did a GET after my post and returned the result as JSON, email was null, but if I POST my xml as:

```
 <User>
   <Email>email@email.com</Email>
   <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
   <LastName>123</LastName>
   <Password>pass</Password>
 </User>
```

Email is no longer null when I do a GET and return it as JSON.  Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

decorate it with the **Order** Parameter in the DataMemberAttribute class:

```
[DataMember(Order = index)]
```

The reflector in the serializer puts it alphabetically.
Unless when decorated like this:

```
[DataMember(Order = 0)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[DataMember(Order = 1)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
[DataMember(Order = 2)]
public string Email { get; set; }
[DataMember(Order = 3)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

[Read more here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx)