# How do I control the order of properties in my JSON output?

Tags: c#, wcf, json, .net-4.0

I have a class, named DataItem, with three properties: Id, DataValue, and CreatedDateTime. The properties are defined in the class in that order from top to bottom. This is also the order I'd like to see the properties in my JSON export. The problem is the properties in the DataItem object and in the JSON export are sorted in alphabetical order. Although there is nothing technically wrong with this format, it is a matter of readability.How do I control the order of properties in the JSON export?

I checked the dataItem wen instantiated and the properties are listed in alphabetical order. This is okay, I understand the potential usability issues of not sorting properties alphabetical.

```
public static List<DataItem>GetAllDataItems()
        {
            List<DataItem> dataItems = new List<DataItem>();

            SqlConnection conn = NetduinoDb.GetConnection();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "Select Id, DataValue, CreatedDateTime from XXX";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataItem dataItem = new DataItem
                {
                    Id = reader["Id"].ToString(),
                    DataValue = reader["DataValue"].ToString(),
                    CreatedDateTime = reader["CreatedDateTime"].ToString()
                };

                dataItems.Add(dataItem);
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();


            return dataItems.ToList();
        }
```

This method is in my service implementation and returns the list of DataItems. I'm thinking I need to do something here but not sure what or how.

```
public List<DataItem> GetCollection()
{
    return DataRetriever.GetAllDataItems();
}
```

Comment: Why are you showing us lots of irrelevant code and don't show the code that matters, i.e. where you serialize your object to JSON? Also, why does the order matter to you? JSON is primarily meant to be read by other programs, not by humans.

Comment: @svick - There isn't much code to show. Whether it's relevant or not, that's what we have. I'm not serializing anything so nothing to show there. As far as the order, that's just what we want. Take a look at the WCF REST Multi-Project Template as that is basically what we're doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF DataContract DataMember order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816478/wcf-datacontract-datamember-order)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `DataContractJsonSerializer` takes into consideration the `DataMember` attribute which has an `Order` property. You can use it to tell the serializer the order of the members you want serialized.

```
[DataContract]
class DataItem
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string DataValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Adjust the order as needed, but this is generally how it is done in WCF.

Comment: Nice, easy solution. Thank you!

Comment: [DataContract] above Class name is must. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think both DataContractJsonSerializer and JSON.NET supports field order.

You can construct JSON string by yourself if Object is as simple as just  having 3 fields.