# JSON object key an value order using Class Object C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have a WCF Service POST method like below:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetResult/{schoolid}")]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "ExamResult")]
CResults GetExamResult(CExamResultQuery pObj, string schoolid);
```

Here is CResults Class:

```
 public class CResults
    {
        public string studentname { get; set; }
        public string studentid { get; set; }
        public string telugu { get; set; }
        public string hindi { get; set; }
        public string english { get; set; }
        public string mathematics { get; set; }
        public string science { get; set; }
        public string social { get; set; }
        public string totalresult { get; set; }

    }
```

I received a JSON string in Post response in my client, But the order of the Key (Value) is different. Here is JSON:

```
"{\"ExamResult\":{\"english\":\"80\",\"hindi\":\"80\",\"mathematics\":\"80\",\"science\":\"80\",\"social\":\"80\",\"studentid\":\"50\",\"studentname\":\"Ashok\",\"telugu\":\"80\",\"totalresult\":\"PASS\"}}"
```

> I see JSON received as alphabetical order not the way as Class
>   variables order. How can I make JSON order the same way as my class.

Here is how I extract Keys & Values from JSON string

```
 JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);

            JSONObject innerObj = jsonRootObject.getJSONObject("ExamResult");

                Iterator<?> keys = innerObj.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) keys.next();
                    mActivity.updateResultsTable(""+key+": "+innerObj.get(key).toString());
                //    Log.i("testExtrace JSONObject", "key " + key + ": value " + innerObj.get(key).toString());

                }
```

> I know I can Extract JSON values using Keys like below:

```
 String studentName= jsonRootObject.getString("studentname");
```

I wanted to change in WCF class only, This may help in extract any JSON in an order which I expect.

Thanks for the support

Comment: Why does the order of extraction matter?  After you extract the values (in whatever order they occur) what prevents you from ordering them in some other way?

Comment: @BrianRogers I know I can extract. Want to know how will it be done in C#.

Comment: You can use `[DataMember(Order = X)]`.  See [How do I control the order of properties in my JSON output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287158/how-do-i-control-the-order-of-properties-in-my-json-output).  But according to the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/), a JSON object is *an unordered set of name/value pairs*, so making your code depend on property order is nonstandard.

Comment: @dbc +1 Thanks for the solution and link. messedup my upvote for you. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataMember(Order) Attribute like below:

```
[DataContract]
public class CResults
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string studentname { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string studentid { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string telugu { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string hindi { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string english { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string mathematics { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string science { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string social { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public string totalresult { get; set; }

}
```