# Order of returned WCF JSON

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF service that returns some JSON from a serialized object:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I've added some extra properties to this class, but now some of the implementations fails because they read it like:

```
string[] ResultLoginValues = e.Result.ToString().Split(',');
```

and it's returned in alphabetically order instead of the old order with the new properties last.

Is there any way I can change the order, or should they rewrite the clients?

Comment: This is why you should use a json parser.

Comment: Maybe this could help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816478/wcf-datacontract-datamember-order

Comment: I'm not the one who wrote the client - but you're completly right! Other implementations (Andorid app for example) which I've tested on doesn't fail because a parser is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solution refer [WCF DataContract DataMember order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816478/wcf-datacontract-datamember-order)

Comment: Same link as Yiğit Yener gave me which worked, so accepting this one.