# Reading POST Request XML - Boolean value always read as false

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, boolean

I'm working on a WCF RESTful web service hosted in IIS. I'm currently working on a fairly simple post request, sending the following XML to the endpoint:

```
<StockListRequestData xmlns="http://myWebService.com/endpoint">
<UserID>2750</UserID>
<StockDatabase>stockLeekRoadVenue</StockDatabase>
<InStockOnly>true</InStockOnly>
</StockListRequestData>
```

This XML matches a `DataContract` on my web service:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://myWebService.com/endpoint")]
public class StockListRequestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StockDatabase { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool InStockOnly { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is the `<InStockOnly>true</InStockOnly>` element, when I set this to `true` or `false` it will always be interpreted as `false`...

Here is the code that handles the request:

```
public StockListResponseData GetListOfProducts(StockListRequestData requestData)
    {
        var stockList = new StockList(requestData.InStockOnly, requestData.StockDatabase);
        StockListResponseData response;
        if (stockList.Any())
        {
            var stockArray = new Stock[stockList.Count];
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var s in stockList)
            {
                stockArray[i] = s;
                i++;
            }
            response = new StockListResponseData
                           {
                               StockList = stockArray,
                               WasSuccessful = true,
                           };
            return response;
        }
        response = new StockListResponseData
                       {
                           WasSuccessful = false
                       };
        return response;
    }
```

The `StockList` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class StockList : List<Stock>
{
    public StockList(bool inStockOnly, string stockDb)
    {
        if (inStockOnly)
        {
            // Get only products that are in stock
            var conn = AndyServerDatabase.ConnectToStockMovementByDb(stockDb);
            conn.Open();
            // Compile SQL query
            var q = new SqlCommand(null, conn) { CommandText = "SELECT StockID, Name, PerBox FROM Stock WHERE InStock = 1;" };

            // Execute query
            var rdr = q.ExecuteReader();

            // Check that the output isn't null
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while(rdr.Read())
                {
                    var id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);
                    var name = rdr[1].ToString();
                    var perBox = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[2]);
                    Add(new Stock(id, name, perBox));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            // Output is null
            conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            // Get all products
            // Get only products that are in stock
            var conn = AndyServerDatabase.ConnectToStockMovementByDb(stockDb);
            conn.Open();
            // Compile SQL query
            var q = new SqlCommand(null, conn) { CommandText = "SELECT StockID, Name, PerBox FROM Stock;" };
            q.Prepare();

            // Execute query
            var rdr = q.ExecuteReader();

            // Check that the output isn't null
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);
                    var name = rdr[1].ToString();
                    var perBox = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[2]);
                    Add(new Stock(id, name, perBox));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            // Output is null
            conn.Close();
        }
        // Add();
    }
}
```

Resultant XML:

```
<StockListResponseData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <StockList xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SMS">
        <a:Stock>
            <a:Id>1</a:Id>
            <a:Name>Smirnoff Vodka (70cl)</a:Name>
            <a:PerBox>6</a:PerBox>
            <a:Quantity>0</a:Quantity>
            <a:Remains>0</a:Remains>
        </a:Stock>
        <a:Stock>
            <a:Id>2</a:Id>
            <a:Name>Jagermeister (70cl)</a:Name>
            <a:PerBox>6</a:PerBox>
            <a:Quantity>0</a:Quantity>
            <a:Remains>0</a:Remains>
        </a:Stock>
    </StockList>
    <WasSuccessful>true</WasSuccessful>
```

I hope this is enough to go on, I've been stumped for ages and just can't figure out why it's behaving in such a way.. if you need additional code I haven't included please feel free to ask.

Many thanks,

Andy

Edit:

To add some context to show what is happening:

For example, I know that:

```
    <a:Stock>
        <a:Id>2</a:Id>
        <a:Name>Jagermeister (70cl)</a:Name>
        <a:PerBox>6</a:PerBox>
        <a:Quantity>0</a:Quantity>
        <a:Remains>0</a:Remains>
    </a:Stock>
```

Has its `InStock` row set to 0, which means that this should not be displayed in the resultant XML if I pass in `true`.

I have changed the StockList constructors `if(inStockOnly)` to `if(!inStockOnly)` - I then pass in `<InStockOnly>true</InStockOnly>` - when it gets to the StockList constructor it is then inverted and the correct data is displayed - so it must be reading it as false by the time it gets to this `if` statement.

If I pass in `<InStockOnly>false</InStockOnly>` it still displays the "correct" results, therefore it is reading it as false until it gets to the inversion!

Likewise if I leave it as `if(inStockOnly)` and pass in `<InStockOnly>false</InStockOnly>` it displays the data for `false`!

I have also added `requestData.InStockOnly` to the StockListResponseData DataContract and there it displays it outputs the value of `requestData.InStockOnly` as `false`.

Comment: Your code looks ok, except that you're not populating Quantity and Remains, so those will always be 0.  Are you certain that the items being returned actually aren't in stock?  Incidentally, the code you're using to populate stockArray isn't necessary.  You should just use Stock[] stockArray = stockList.ToArray();

Comment: Yeah I thought that might cause some confusion, the purpose of the `<InStockOnly>true</InStockOnly` element is to check against a `InStock` row in the stock table - which is of `bit` type. The Quantity and Remains elements are irrelevant.

Comment: So how have you verified that InStockOnly actually is always false? Your post doesn't mention that detail or give anything to demonstrate that it's always false.

Comment: I'll update the question with more detail.

Comment: I've added some detail about how I have been trying to troubleshoot this to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, and that is a stumper.  Have you verified that UserID and StockDatabase have the values you're passing in?  Is there any code you're not showing that runs between the time the request is received and the time GetListOfProducts() is called?

Comment: StockDatabase provides the database name for the specified companies stock listings - seeing as I am getting data out that must be getting to the `AndyServerDatabase.ConnectToStockMovementByDb(stockDb);` section of code. UserID is not implemented in code but I will check I am getting something from that, I will also try using a different tag name and see if that makes any difference. Shot in the dark! And no there shouldn't be any code called before GetListOfProducts() that is the Web Service endpoint.

Comment: Well I renamed the `InStockOnly` DataMember to `Only` and tried again - no avail. I also checked that `UserID` is getting through - it is.

Comment: Fixed it!

I changed the datatype of `<InStockOnly>` to a `string`, I also changed the `if(inStockOnly)` to `if(inStockOnly.Equals("1"))` - I then passed in `<InStockOnly>1</InStockOnly>` and I got a `NullReferenceException`. Weird! 

So I decided to re-order my Request XML, moving the `InStockOnly` element to the top - and it worked!

So I switched the data type back to `bool` and now everything is working perfectly, if anyone knows WHY this happens I would very much like to know! 

Very odd! I will update this with my answer once it has been on here for 8 hours - not enough reputation...

Comment: I was able to find a plausible explanation thanks to your discovery, and added it below so it's not crammed into a tiny space. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your discovery has led me to the explanation, and someone with a problem similar to yours:

[WCF DataContract DataMember order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816478/wcf-datacontract-datamember-order)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx

> Next in order are the current type’s data members that do not have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set, in alphabetical order.

When the order of data members is not explicitly specified, their serialization order is alphabetical.  That explains why InStockOnly worked when it was moved to the top, because it's first alphabetically. On the other hand, why StockDatabase worked is a bit of a mystery, because that's after UserId alphabetically (does AndyServerDatabase.ConnectToStockMovementByDb() use a default value if StockDb is null?).

For the sake of argument, if for whatever reason you wanted to keep the order you have there, you could do this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://myWebService.com/endpoint")]
public class StockListRequestData
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string StockDatabase { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public bool InStockOnly { get; set; }
}
```

In fact, it's probably a good practice to explicitly indicate the order, so adding new properties later doesn't break anything.

Comment: That makes total sense, and yeah the database connection seems to default to the same database and that's why it's working fine - I will need to fix that. Well at least its uncovered, thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion above and it still didn't work!  Kept searching and found another solution, actually setting the 'Specified' property to true:

```
PackageImagesPayload payload = new PackageImagesPayload();
payload.UsesSplitBy = usesSplitBy;
payload.UsesSplitBySpecified = true;
```