# How to format json response in WCF rest service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, object

I'am building a service which has to return a json response:

> {"Content":{"API":"Some API","DisplayVersion":"1.0","Version":1},"Status":"OK"}

I'am finding it difficult to format it the way I want. I'am getting a response in this fashion:

> {"API":"Some API","DisplayVersion":"1.0","Version":"1"}

Here is my code for the same:

```
  [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle =
 WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat =
 WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
 UriTemplate = "")]

         public Info GetSystemInfo()
         {
                 return new Info()
                 {
                     API = "Some API",
                     DisplayVersion = "1.0",
                     Version = "1"
                 };

         }

 [DataContract]
   public class Info
     {
         [DataMember]
         public string API { get; set; }
          [DataMember]
         public string DisplayVersion { get; set; }
          [DataMember]
          public string Version { get; set; }
     }
```

I tried structuring my class like this:

```
   [DataContract]
    public class Info
    {
        [DataMember]
        public class Content
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string API { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string DisplayVersion { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Version { get; set; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

How should I go about It?

Comment: I guess you need the `Order` attribute just [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816478/wcf-datacontract-datamember-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to structure your classes like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Info
{
    [DataMember]
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    [DataMember]
    public string API { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DisplayVersion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** Using info:

```
    Info info = new Info() 
    { 
        Status = "OK", 
        Content = new Content() { API = "Some Api", DisplayVersion = "1.0", Version = 1 } 
    };
```

Comment: And how do I pass data to it?

Comment: That's a sample for using `Info`, you can use it in `GetSystemInfo()`

Comment: @user1650891, one other useful thing, in VS2012 and above, there are couple of useful Edit menu command, which are: Pase JSON as Classes and Pase XML as Classes located in EDIT>Paste Special, take a look at them too, they help a lot.

Comment: Yes sure, I will go through this.

Comment: I would like to how to make a datamember optional.